# Does gedit have a maximum column length and how to counter that?

Tags: python, gedit

very simple question:

I am writing my data in a text file in the format(say):

```
name  val1 val2 val3 

file1  20   33   44

file2  30   22   22 

file3  20   12   12
```

Now I have about 100 values i.e. data goes up to val100, but writing this is gedit means that after about 15 the next val goes to the next line. I am trying to read these in python and manipulate so have trouble if my first val i.e. val1 and 15th i.e. val15 are both in the same column. I have tried using geany to produce the text file but it seems there is a column limit? Is there a way I could get around it? Ofcourse my other option would be to read data off an excel file but I want to pursue this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gedit as well as Geany are having virtual line wrapping which helps you reading a long line but not neccesarly wrting this to a file. On Geany oyu can toggle it via Menu or keystroke: http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#document-keybindings